# Getting a CALayer's rounded corner content area outline  as a clipping path

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I can create a `CALayer` using `[CALayer layer]` and then have rounded corners using `layer.cornerRadius = x`.

After I do this, I have a rounded rectangle layer. Is it possible for me to extract this rounded rectangle outline as a path without re-creating the path myself?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want the path then surely it's easy enough to just make one?

```
UIBezierPath *roundedRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:layer.bounds
                                                       cornerRadius:layer.cornerRadius];
```

If you need to use this in `CoreGraphics` then just ask for it's `CGPath`

```
roundedRect.CGPath;
```

Comment: I understand I can recreate the path, but wanted to know if I can extract it instead as I said.

Comment: No, you can’t. Paul.s’s code will give you an equivalent path, though. Why?